# How to have custom checkout fields in ajax checkout in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, webhooks

I have an Ajax checkout on my woocommerce installation and I am trying to capture the custom fields on the checkout. I am using below code to try to capture the field called add_gift_box, the field appears fine on my checkout page.

```
     add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta' );

function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    if ($_POST['add_gift_box']) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_add_gift_box', esc_attr($_POST['add_gift_box']));
    }
}
```

When I press "place order" button it creates a new order but the value of this field does not get saved in the database. I don't think even the hook gets fired. As I said everything is being handled by Ajax. The checkout page is one page checkout.

I need help sorting this out. Thanks in advance.

UPDATE

I am setting the field as follows:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', 'add_box_option_to_checkout' );

function add_box_option_to_checkout( $checkout ) {
    woocommerce_form_field( 'add_gift_box', array(
        'type'          => 'radio',
        'class'         => array('add_gift_box form-row-wide'),
        'label_class'         => array('checkbox'),
        'input_class'         => array('input-checkbox'),
            'required'     => true,
            'options' => array(
                'option_1' => 'option1</br>' ,
                'option_2' =>'option2</br>',
                'option_3' =>'option3</br>',
                'option_4' =>'option4</br>',
                'option_5' =>'option5</br>',
                'option_6' =>'option6</br>',
                'option_7' =>'option7</br>',
            ),
        'label'         => __('Select Option'),
        'placeholder'   => __(''),
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'add_gift_box' ));


}
```

Comment: you should use something like: `if ( ! empty( $_POST['add_gift_box'] ) ) {` … As we don't know how you are setting this custom field, is difficult to find out what is going wrong and to test it. See official related documentation: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/

Comment: I just updated the question with the way field is being set.

Comment: Your code seems fine. Have you placed the add_action for woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta in your theme's functions.php or maybe in another file or within a code block where it is parsed too late or even never?

Comment: This whole code is in functions.php file of the activated theme. I am not why place order button is not firing this hook at all. One question I may ask is whether the hook "woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta" only get fired if the order is processed successfully? Because I am trying to test this with failed/declined payment orders. The order is created in the backend without this info though. 

Second question is, how can I test whether this hook is fired or not?

Answer (score 0):

here is a plugin to add custom field on checkout page woocomerce https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-custom-checkout-field/

or if you want to add by code you can follow codding from here

https://www.cloudways.com/blog/custom-field-woocommerce-checkout-page/

add_action('woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'customise_checkout_field');

```
function customise_checkout_field($checkout)
{
    echo '<div id="customise_checkout_field"><h2>' . __('Heading') . '</h2>';
    woocommerce_form_field('customised_field_name', array(
        'type' => 'text',
        'class' => array(
            'my-field-class form-row-wide'
        ) ,
        'label' => __('Customise Additional Field') ,
        'placeholder' => __('Guidence') ,
        'required' => true,
    ) , $checkout->get_value('customised_field_name'));
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: So, I have already added the field on the checkout and it is showing up fine. I think the problem is with the Ajax checkout. When somebody clicks on place order button, it is not firing woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta hook at all. I am not sure why. Also is it possible to debug if a hook is fired at all?

Comment: Just updated the question with the code I am using to set the field.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a plugin activated which creates the order by hooking into `woocommerce_create_order` filter? I don't see any other reason why add_gift_box isn't saved or why `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta` isn't firing.

The original code from includes/class-wc-checkout.php is

```
    /**
     * Action hook to adjust order before save.
     * @since 3.0.0
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', $order, $data );

    // Save the order.
    $order_id = $order->save();

    do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', $order_id, $data );
```

So, you could create log files in your themes directory to see which hooks are firing like this:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', function ($order_id) {
    file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta.log', 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta fired for order id ' . $order_id);
});
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order', function () {
    file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/woocommerce_checkout_create_order.log', 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order fired');
});
```

Comment: I am not sure what you meant by activating the plugin. The code is already in functions.php for that particular theme. So it's not a plugin. I tried using your code and when I clicked on place order, it did not create any log file at all. So I assume the two hooks were not fired. I am stuck now :(

Comment: My other hunch is that since the site is using a Ajax checkout, it is not firing these hooks. I am not sure if that could be true or not.

Comment: What I meant is a third-party plugin. The create_order method in which the the two hooks should fire starts with these lines:
  // Give plugins the opportunity to create an order themselves.
  if ( $order_id = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_create_order', null, $this ) ) {
   return $order_id;
  }
So, if there is a plugin hooking into woocommerce_create_order and returning an order_id, WooCommerce's create_order is practically overwritten and the hooks won't fire if they are not implemented by the plugin. You can test this by deactivating all plugins that could influence the checkout.